# Browser does not remember password during login

Tags: forms, extjs, authentication, extjs4, extjs4.1

An [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945553/233286) mentioned a method using the `el` config in order to make the browser remember passwords. Howewer, the `el` config no longer exists in ExtJS 4.1.

Now, what should I do?

Comment: Please don't put tags in your title: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it should be **contentEl** instead of **el** but I do this another way.  You can build the entire thing with ExtJS directly.  The only twist is that Ext fields will be created with the **autocomplete=off** attribute by default, so I use a derived class to override that.

```
Ext.define('ACField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text',

    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.each(this.fieldSubTpl, function(oneTpl, idx, allItems) {
            if (Ext.isString(oneTpl)) {
                allItems[idx] = oneTpl.replace('autocomplete="off"', 'autocomplete="on"');
            }
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    new Ext.panel.Panel({
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 300,
        height: 100,
        autoEl: {
            tag: 'form',
            action: 'login.php',
            method: 'post'
        },  
        items: [
            new ACField({
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'username',
                fieldLabel: 'Username'
            }), 
            new ACField({
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'password',
                fieldLabel: 'Password',
                inputType: 'password'
            }), 
        ],
        buttons: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Log in',
            type: 'submit',
            preventDefault: false
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe a combination of this answer and mine are actually what the asker probably needs. I forgot about the autocomplete off thing, and now I vaguely remember something about it

Comment: @lagnat This works for me in IE9, but in Firefox and Chrome it doesn't prompt to save the password.

Comment: Are you trying to use an ajax form save or a regular form submit?

Comment: @PaulSchroeder Both: first an AJAX submit to validate the username and password, and then a regular form submit if that checks out.

Comment: @JohnnyHK It's working on FF for me, but I'm seeing the same problem with Chrome.  I'm guessing that Chrome requires the markup to be in place on the page rather than generated after Ready and I can't see any way to do that other than to totally hand-write the HTML with the ExtJS styles.  I eagerly await a better solution, if it exists.

Comment: No problems with Fx and Opera. Chrome doesn't prompt "save passwod". On IE9 it asks me to activate ActiveX, on file. If I am on intranet it asks me to activate some intranet settings.

Comment: No problems while IE9 is on the internet.

Comment: Firefox propts "save password" and then it saves it but then when you revisit th page it is unable to show/replace the password. As if it didn't saved it.

Answer (score 6):

The answer from lagnat was mostly correct, to get this also working on Chrome and Firefox the following is required:

1) Override default ExtJS Textfield behavior for autocomplete (copied from lagnat):

```
Ext.define('ACField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text',

    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.each(this.fieldSubTpl, function(oneTpl, idx, allItems) {
            if (Ext.isString(oneTpl)) {
                allItems[idx] = oneTpl.replace('autocomplete="off"', 'autocomplete="on"');
            }
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

2) Make sure the textfields are within a `<form>` tag: (see answer from lagnat), since ExtJS 4 the `<form>` tag is no longer present in a FormPanel.

```
    autoEl: {
        tag: 'form',
        action: '/j_spring_security_check',
        method: 'post'
    },
```

3) Make sure there is a `<form>` present in the HTML, with the same `<input>` names:

```
            items:[
                Ext.create('ACField',{
                    fieldLabel: 'Username',
                    name:'j_username',
                    inputId: 'username',
                    allowBlank:false,
                    selectOnFocus:true
                }),
                Ext.create('ACField',{
                    fieldLabel:'Password',
                    name:'j_password',
                    inputId: 'password',
                    xtype:'textfield',
                    allowBlank:false,
                    inputType:'password'
                })
            ],
```

and within the HTML the regular form with same input names:

```
<body>
<div id="login-panel">
    <form id="loginForm" action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"/>" method="post">
        <input class="x-hidden" type="text" id="username" name="j_username"/>
        <input class="x-hidden" type="password" id="password" name="j_password"/>
    </form>
</div>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript</noscript>
</body>
```

With all these changes in place, saving username/password works in IE, Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

There is the autoRender property which will allow you to apply the Extjs field to an already existing element on the page.  So if you set up your basic form in html, the browser should recognize the fields for the form as login info, and then Extjs will overlay itself onto that form if you use the autoRender with a reference to the correct fields (and also the button on the form to a submit type button in your basic html form) it should work correctly.
Also, keep in mind that the browser probably will not recognize an ajax call for logging in and you may need to use the basic form submission.  I have a working example in my application, but I would have a hard time trying to pull out application specific code so have an example for here.  Please comment if you need the example and I may be able to get back to you by monday.

Comment: I'd appreciate seeing your example.  I've tried lagnat's solution and I can't get it to save the password on chrome and firefox.

Comment: yeah...  I remember having the same issue...  let me see what I can figure out.

Comment: Apparently our login still uses Ext 3.2.1, we still have some places in our app that are still on the old version apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @Lagnat does not work for ExtJS 4.2.1 and 4.2.2. It might be due to removal of [`type`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-type) config from button. What we need is standard submit button `<input type="submit">` for the button. So I added it on the button with `opacity: 0`. Below is my working code (Tested working on Firefox 27, Chrome 33, Safari 5.1.7, IE 11. Autofill/Autosave password should be enabled for browser):

```
Ext.create('Ext.FormPanel', {
    width: 400,
    height: 500,
    padding: '45 0 0 25',
    autoEl: {
        tag: 'form',
        action: 'login.php',
        method: 'post'
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Username',
        name: 'username',
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function() {
                this.inputEl.set({
                    'autocomplete': 'on'
                });
            }
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Password',
        inputType: 'password',
        name: 'username',
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function() {
                this.inputEl.set({
                    'autocomplete': 'on'
                });
            }
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'LOG IN',
        width: 100,
        height: 35,
        preventDefault: false,
        clickEvent: 'click',
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function() {
                this.el.createChild({
                    tag: 'input',
                    type: 'submit',
                    value: 'LOG IN',
                    style: 'width: 100px; height: 35px; position: relative; top: -31px; left: -4px; opacity: 0;'
                });
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I recommend using the built in Cookie functionality of ExtJS.

- You can read a cookie using: readCookie('password);
- You can create a cookie using: createCookie('password', "pass123", 30); // save for 30 days

Then you can use basic business logic to auto-populate your formField with the stored password.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Cookie storage is insecure - the password is stored in cleartext and it's easily accessible by anyone with access to the browser (among other issues). See the accepted answer in the original linked question. It's better to use the browser's built-in functionality for this.